# Post con Ajax siempre da error pero igual funciona

Tags: jquery, ajax

SOLUCIÓN: Una de las soluciones dadas (que fue la que me funcionó fue eliminar `dataType : 'json',` luego si la ruta queda como en mi caso `/search/search/undefined` eso lo solucioné cambiando `window.location.href = response.redirect;` por `window.location.href = '';`.

tengo el siguiente código en el cual primero obtengo en un array los checkbox seleccionados para luego hacer un Post de dichos datos que lo único que hace es cambiarle el estado en la base de datos, o sea, los campos por defecto se encuentran en la base de datos con el valor "Activo" y la idea es que despés de haber seleccionado varios de ellos en el formulario y hacer click en el botón "Archivar" el estado de los campos en la base de datos cambie a "Archivados" lo que no sé es por qué la función nunca entra a Success, siempre da error y se dispara el alert de "No funciona" pero si recargo la página o voy a la bd el valor de los campos cambió con éxito, ¿alguien sabe a qué se puede deber eso? gracias de antemano.

CÓDIGO DEL FORMULARIO DE LA PARTE DE LOS CHECKBOX:

```
<ul id='listResult'>
    <?php for($i=0;$i<count(1);$i++)
    {
        ?>
        <li><input id ='opt'type='checkbox' name='opt' value='<?= $dato['id']?>'><?= $dato['desc'].' - '.$dato['date'].' - '.$dato['status']?></li>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

CÓDIGO PARTE DEL AJAX:

```
function archivar()
{
    var busquedas = [];
    $('#listResult input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function()
    {
        busquedas.push($(this).attr('value'));
    });
    if(busquedas.length>0)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'search/search',
            data : {opt:busquedas},
            type : 'POST',
            dataType : 'json',

            success : function(response){
                window.location.href = response.redirect;
                alert("funciona");
            },
            error: function(error){
                alert("No funciona");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65487/discussion-on-question-by-ccccccccc-post-con-ajax-siempre-da-error-pero-igual-fu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que al poner `dataType : 'json'` le estás indicando a jQuery que se debe esperar un JSON válido cómo respuesta, de lo contrario será tomado cómo si fuera una respuesta con error

Lo que debes revisar es la respuesta que te da el servidor. Y debes validar que esa respuesta sea un JSON válido. Para probarlo de manera sencilla, quita el `dataType : 'json'` y has un `console.log` de la respuesta, así:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'search/search',
    data : {opt:busquedas},
    type : 'POST',

    success : function(response){
        console.log(response);
        //window.location.href = response.redirect;
        alert("funciona");
    },
    error: function(error){
        alert("No funciona");
    }
});
```

Comment: Hola, gracias, a pesar de que ya lo había solucionado ésta es la respuesta útil además de que me diste una explicación del por qué se daba el error, saludos!