# Respuesta erronea de petición Ajax con jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http

Estoy empezando a programar peticiones ajax con jQuery. Como prueba, he hecho que al hacer click en un botón, se realice una petición ajax a un servlet Java, el cual escribirá en consola los datos enviados y responderá con una cadena de texto.
El código JS es el siguiente:

```
$("#boton").click(function(){
    $.ajax({

        url : 'ActionServlet',
        type : 'POST',
        data : {
            'nombre' : 'miguel',
            'apellido' : 'rodriguez'
        },
        dataType:'json',
        success : function(data) {              
            alert('Data: '+data);
        },
        error : function(request,error)
        {
            alert("Request: "+JSON.stringify(request));
        }
    });
});
```

El código del método doPost del Servlet es este:

```
response.setContentType( "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" );
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String nombre = request.getParameter("nombre");
    String apellido = request.getParameter("apellido");
    System.out.println("Nombre: " + nombre);
    System.out.println("Apellido: " + apellido);

    out.println("Comunicación realizada");
```

Todo funciona correctamente. El servlet recibe los datos y los imprime. El problema que tengo es que la respuesta del servlet entra en la función de error, y no en la success, y no entiendo por qué, ya que la petición se ha realizado correctamente.
Lo que imprime el alert de la parte de error del método ajax es:

```
Request: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"Comunicación realizada\r\n","status":200,"statusText":"OK"}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Saludos

Comment: tuve un error similar, puede ser el mismo, para que no entre en error, tiene que devolver exactamente eso, eso decir, si tienes una clase con un parámetro que se llama tiempo, tiene que devolver tiempo, no Tiempo, ni Time, los parámetros tienen que ser idénticos. Comprueba esto, me llevo tiempo

Comment: por cierto, tienes que poner el código del servlet

Comment: No entiendo tu primer comentario @Iria, ¿quieres decir que los parametros del ajax tienen que coincidir con lo que devuelve el servlet? Si es así, un ajax puede mandar unos parámetros y recibir otros totalmente diferentes y no por eso tiene que ir por el error.

Comment: ¿Entonces cual es el problema? @Iria, el código del método doPost del servlet está puesto, creo que el resto de código del servlet es irrelevante para este problema. Gracias por contestar

Comment: Dicho esto, veo que tu ajax espera un `json` y tu estas pintando en la respuesta un `String`. Creo que esto puede ser tu problema. Puedes cambiar el `dataType:'json'` por `dataType:'text'` o meter tus datos en un `json` y devolverlo.

Comment: Correcto, ahora me funciona bien!! Creía que ese dataType hacía referencia a los datos que se enviaban, no a los que se recibían. Muchísimas gracias

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Post con Ajax siempre da error pero igual funciona](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/101647/post-con-ajax-siempre-da-error-pero-igual-funciona)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu ajax estas indicando que lo que va a recibir es un `JSON`:

```
dataType:'json'
```

En cambio tu estas pintando `String`. por lo que puedes cambiar el `dataType`:

```
dataType:'text'
```

O también puedes meter tus datos en un `JSON`:

```
JSONObject jsonRespuesta= new JSONObject();
jsonRespuesta.put("respuesta", "Comunicación realizada");

out.println(jsonRespuesta);
```

Y después en el `success` acceder a la `respuesta` mediante:

```
data.respuesta
```